# JavaScript execution hangs page momentarily

Tags: javascript, jquery, freeze

I have a web application which uses **jQuery/JavaScript** heavily. It holds a large array in memory, and the user filters it by typing in a textbox.

Problem: When the filtering algorithm runs, **the application becomes non-responsive** and  the browser may even ask the user whether to let the script continue.

Optimally, I would like the filter function to run in a **separate thread**, to avoid non-responsiveness. Is this possible in any way? Alternatively, I would like to show a rotating hourglass or similar, but browsers seem unable to display animated GIFs when running heavy scripts.

What is the best way of attacking the problem?

Comment: Use a database/file and make AJAX calls instead of keeping it in the users memory so you can make it async and then there's no blocking.

Comment: Web workers maybe (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers)

Comment: @Dan Lee: That's true, but that would force me to do a major rewrite of the application.

Comment: (Unless you use web workers) JS runs in a single thread, the same thread that the browser uses to update the page. You can rewrite the filtering algorithm to use `setTimeout()` to break the processing into smaller chunks and give the browser a chance to respond in between each chunk. This technique also avoids the long-running script prompt that browsers display.

Comment: @Ilia Frenkel: Thanks for the tip. I'll have a look at it. Seems the support for it is patchy though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers execute scripts in the main event processing thread. This means any long running scripts can holdup the browser queue.

You should split your filter logic into chunks and run them on [timeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) callback's. You may use a gap of 0 mills between executions. 0 milli's is just a suggestion to the browser, but the browser will use the gap between subsequent callbacks to clear its event queue. Timeout's is generally how long running scripts are ought to be executed in the browser environment to prevent the page from "hanging".

Comment: Yes, as suggested by @nnnnnn above, I suppose this is the most reasonable way to avoid non-responsiveness. I suppose Web Workers will be the way to go when its supported by major browsers.

Comment: @Gruber Unfortunately IE does not have it yet.

Comment: For the record, I successfully employed this methodology to solve my problem.

Comment: IE should only be considered a major browser if you expect the majority of your visitors to be senor citizens.

Answer (score 2):

This type of job is what [Web Workers](http://ejohn.org/blog/web-workers/) were designed for, support is [patchy, but improving](http://caniuse.com/webworkers).

Comment: Thanks, that's new to me. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @codebox, Huge Processing on Web Worker hangs on Chrome (v34) as well

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on my comment from earlier, given that you are processing an array you are probably using a `for` loop. You can easily refactor a simple `for` loop to use `setTimeout()` so that the work is broken up into chunks and the browser gets a chance to handle screen paints and user interaction between each chunk. Simple example:

```
// Generic function to execute a callback a given number
// of times with a given delay between each execution
function timeoutLoop(fn, startIndex, endIndex, delay) {
    function doIteration() {
        if (startIndex < endIndex){
            fn(startIndex++);
            setTimeout(doIteration, delay);
        }
    }
    doIteration();
}

// pass your function as callback
timeoutLoop(function(i) {
   // current iteration processing here, use i if needed;
}, 0, 100, 0);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/LeZxM/1/

That's just something I cobbled together to show the general idea, but obviously it can be expanded in various ways, e.g., you might like to add a `chunkSize` parameter to `timeoutLoop()` to say how many loop iterations to do in each timeout (adding a conventional loop around the call to `fn()`), etc.

Comment: I used your idea to implement a solution to my problem. It worked out really well.