# Display animated gif while carrying out Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an intensive jQuery function that takes place on my page when a button is clicked. I display a loading gif while this takes place. This can take around 5 seconds.

The problem I have is that the animated gif stops spinning while the JavaScript is processing, causing users to think it's crashed. Is there a way to ensure the loading gif remains spinning?

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
  var text = "";
  var i = 0;
  while (i < 50500) {
    text += "<br>The number is " + i;
    i++;
  }
  $("p").append(text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://thinkfuture.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/loading_spinner.gif" />
<button>click here</button>
<p></p>
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/wgh2oseu/1/

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12419667/526704

Comment: No; Javascript is single-threaded.  What are you doing that is slow?

Comment: Did you notice this thread? Maybe helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191413/why-does-my-spinner-gif-stop-while-jquery-ajax-call-is-running

Comment: I have already come across those questions. Unfortunately none of them provide a solution.